# Can a dll made in c# be used in a golang application

Tags: c#, .net, go

I have created a basic class that adds two numbers in c#. I have built it into a dll but when attempting to call it in golang I am unsuccessful.

Is this possible currently in golang? If so can someone provide a example how to do this?

Edit: I have included the last attempt I made at doing this. The C# dll is simply a method that adds the two numbers that are passed in.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    var mod = syscall.NewLazyDLL("MathForGo.dll")
    var proc = mod.NewProc("Add");
    proc.Call(2,3);
    fmt.Printf("%v",proc)
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to do this? Can you please show us some code?

Comment: I have added the last attempt I made. This version is causing a error when attempting to call go install with   _undefined: syscall.NewLazyDLL_

Answer (score 11):

There is a project on Github that aims to do this.

https://github.com/matiasinsaurralde/go-dotnet

C# assemblies are not the same as C or C++ and will not load using syscall like we might want.