# Using .net C# DLL in Golang?

Tags: c#, windows, go, dll

I am working on a project in which I am using dll provided by http://aforgenet.com/ in C#. I need to use the same thing in Golang. I have checked out [CGO Documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/), but it is about C, not C#. Since binding in C# and C are different, I doubt it will work with CGO. How can I use C# DLL in Golang?

I am not able to understand the example given in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314958/can-a-dll-made-in-c-sharp-be-used-in-a-golang-application). It is about system libraries. If someone can give a very basic example of code written in C# being imported in Golang, I will be very grateful.

Comment: [go-dotnet - Go wrapper for the .NET Core Runtime.](https://github.com/matiasinsaurralde/go-dotnet) might work.

Comment: Another solution is to wrap the C#DLL as a COM I/F. [C# DLL (Class Library) functions called from Go Language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44447318/9014308)