# Pass pointer to a pointer in Go DLL Syscall

Tags: c#, go, dll, system-calls

If I have the following C# `DllImport` which is importing a non-C# DLL and I want to port it over to Go, how would I go about doing that?

```cs
    [DllImport("my.dll", EntryPoint = "Greet", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int Greet(IntPtr name, ref IntPtr greetings);
```

I've run into problems figuring out how to pass a pointer to a pointer which is needed for the `greetings` parameter (I assume since the type is `ref IntPtr`, I'm not that familiar at all with C#). The dll function will populate the memory pointed to by the pointer that I provide which I'll use in subsequent syscalls. Here's what I've got so far,

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

var (
    MyDll = syscall.MustLoadDLL("my.dll")
    greet = MyDll.MustFindProc("Greet")
)

func Greet(name string) error {
    nameP, err := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(name)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // I need to provide a pointer to a pointer for greetings. How can I allocate some memory here
    // then pass a pointer to its pointer? I tried this: create a handle with a zero-value, then
    // take a pointer to it, then pass a pointer to the pointer as the second parameter to Call but
    // the pointer becomes nil after the Call.
    handle := syscall.Handle(0)
    handleP := &handle
    r1, _, _ := greet.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(nameP)), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&handleP)))
    if r1 == 0 {
        return fmt.Errorf("there was an error")
    }
    return nil
}
```

I'm open to any and all suggestions including links and resources that might help me get a better grasp on this syscall and unsafe stuff. Thanks!

Comment: After further research, it looks like my problem might be related to the fact that `IntPtr` in C# is actually a struct (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.intptr?view=net-5.0), so it's likely that I need to create a compatible struct in Go, then provide a pointer to it in my syscall. No idea how to do that, I'll keep searching.

Comment: Probably relevant : [Can a dll made in c# be used in a golang application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314958), [C# DLL (Class Library) functions called from Go Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44447318)

Comment: Thanks @LeGEC but I should probably clarify in the post that this is not a C# DLL, it’s just being imported using C# and my goal is to duplicate what C# is doing.

Comment: You might also include the code (C#) which actually uses this function. That might help you understand how to do the same in Go.

Comment: @ClarkMcCauley : can you clarify what kind of dll is `my.dll` then ? a regular Win32 dll ? does [the information written in this post](https://medium.com/@justen.walker/breaking-all-the-rules-using-go-to-call-windows-api-2cbfd8c79724) apply ?

Comment: A pointer to pointer is just an integer pointing to another integer holding the address an a value. Whatever type of value. You have to double deref to read the actual value.

Comment: @Martin.Martinsson my problem is not doing something with it, it's passing the pointer to a pointer in the first place. As you can see in my example I'm trying to pass a pointer to a pointer, but it's coming back as `nil` after the syscall. Is my syntax bad?

Comment: @LeGEC I did read that article, it was pretty helpful. I think my problem here is that I am unable to replicate the C# DLL import signature. It says that the first parameter is an `IntPtr` to a string, which I can do successfully, but the second parameter `ref IntPtr` is what I can't figure out how to do.

Comment: If I understand correctly : you are reading how a C# library imports that dll to try to guess how the go code should be written. What I was indirectly suggesting is : look directly at the C header files for your dll (you do have access to those, right ?).

Comment: @LeGEC I do not, if I did, this would likely be pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it would help if you could show how the C# `Greet` method is used. A method in isolation its quite hard to understand especially when the parameter is the equivalent of `void **` which means anything can go in.

TL;DR
`ref IntPtr` is probably just a `**struct{}` where you don't have to allocate any struct. The library will simply manage the memory for you. You just need to give it a pointer to "*MyStruct" so that it can change you "*MyStruct" to actually point to the internal resource.

## `REF`

The C# `ref` keyword is quite well explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref). Basically it allows a pass by reference for any type.
The following declaration in C#

```
void Increment(ref value) { ... }

int counter = 10;
Increment(ref counter);
// counter is now 11
Increment(counter); // won't compile must be passed with 'ref'
Increment(null); // won't compile
```

is equivalent to  C++

```
void Increment(int& value) { ... }

int counter;
Increment(counter);
// counter is now 11
Increment(null); // won't compile
```

A reference which should not be null.

## `IntPtr`

`IntPtr` is usually used to represent pointers and allows for interop between native and CLR (C#) programs.

If a C program has the following signature

```
void Increment(int* value);
```

a C# program could call it in one of a few ways

```
[DllImport("example.dll")]
static unsafe extern void Increment(int* value); // this way allows null to be passed in

unsafe {
    int counter = 10;
    Increment(&10);
}
```

,

```
[DllImport("example.dll")]
static extern void Increment(ref int value);

int counter = 10;
Increment(ref counter);
```

If a C program has the following signature

```
void AllocateStruct(struct MyStruct** ppStruct);
void IncrementStruct(struct MyStruct* pStruct);
```

then

```
[DllImport("example.dll")]
static extern void AllocateStruct(ref IntPtr ppStruct);
// static unsafe extern void AllocateStruct(MyStruct** ppStruct)

[DllImport("example.dll")]
static extern void IncrementStruct(IntPtr pStruct);
// static unsafe extern void IncrementStruct(MyStruct* pStruct);

IntPtr pMyStruct;
AllocateStruct(ref pMyStruct);
IncrementStruct(pMyStruct);
// Free My Struct

// If you need to get inside the struct then
// MyStruct myStruct = Marshal.StructureToPtr<MyStruct>(pMyStruct)
// Often you don't (need to) or (should not) manipulate the struct directly so keeping it as IntPtr is perfectly acceptable.
```

From the example above you can see `MyStruct` is more of a **token/reference** than anything else. `ref IntPtr` allows you to pass a reference to the location which you will use to store your token/reference after the library allocates it on your behalf. Then all the other methods will usually just use the reference `IntPtr` to perform subsequent manipulations on it. Basically Object Orientated Programming without classes.

## "Real" Life Example with `ref IntPtr`

It is a bit quick and dirty and error handling leave a lot to be desired.
It shows the `C`, `C#` and `Go` versions which call the same `GetSecurityInfo`
and `LookupAccountSid` Win32 library functions.

The only real use case I can find for `ref IntPtr` is `type**`/`void**` so that the library can allocate the memory for you or give you a pointer to memory it has already allocated.

### C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "accctrl.h"
#include "aclapi.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "advapi32.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // --- get the executing program's file path and handle -----

    LPTSTR executablePath = argv[0];
    _tprintf(TEXT("Opening File %s\n"), executablePath);

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(
        executablePath,
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return EXIT_FAILURE;

    // -------------------------------------------------

    // --------- Get the owner SID of the file ---------

    PSID pSidOwner = NULL;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = NULL;

    DWORD dwRtnCode = GetSecurityInfo(
        hFile,
        SE_FILE_OBJECT,
        OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
        &pSidOwner,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &pSD);

    if (dwRtnCode != ERROR_SUCCESS) return EXIT_FAILURE;

    // -------------------------------------------------

    // ------- 

    TCHAR AcctName[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD dwAcctName = MAX_PATH;

    TCHAR DomainName[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD dwDomainName = MAX_PATH;

    SID_NAME_USE eUse = SidTypeUnknown;

    BOOL bRtnBool = LookupAccountSid(
        NULL,           // local computer
        pSidOwner,
        &AcctName,
        &dwAcctName,
        DomainName,
        &dwDomainName,
        &eUse);

    if (bRtnBool == FALSE) return EXIT_FAILURE;

    _tprintf(TEXT("Account Owner = %s\n"), AcctName);
    _tprintf(TEXT("Account Owner's Domain = %s\n"), DomainName);

    return 0;
}
```

### C#

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

public class Example
{
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    static extern uint GetSecurityInfo(
        IntPtr handle,
        uint ObjectType,
        uint SecurityInfo,
        ref IntPtr ppsidOwner, // <-- HERE
        IntPtr ppsidGroup, // bit hacky (in safe C# you must "pass a reference" in C you can pass a pointer to a pointer or null)
        IntPtr ppDacl,
        IntPtr ppSacl,
        ref IntPtr ppSecurityDescriptor // <-- HERE
    );

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool LookupAccountSid(
        string lpSystemName,
        IntPtr Sid,
        StringBuilder lpName,
        ref uint cchName,
        StringBuilder ReferencedDomainName,
        ref uint cchReferencedDomainName,
        out uint peUse);

    const uint ERROR_SUCCESS = 0;
    const uint OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x00000001;
    const uint SE_FILE_OBJECT = 1;

    public static void Main()
    {

        // get the executing program's file path and handle
        string executablePath = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().GetValue(0).ToString();
        IntPtr hFile = File.Open(executablePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
            .SafeFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle();

        IntPtr pSidOwner = IntPtr.Zero; // some internal struct you shouldn't allocate or modify (acts like a token)
        IntPtr pSD = IntPtr.Zero; // some internal struct you shouldn't allocate or modify (acts like a token)

        // vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

        uint dwRtnCode = GetSecurityInfo(
            hFile,
            SE_FILE_OBJECT,
            OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
            ref pSidOwner, // <-- HERE
            IntPtr.Zero,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            ref pSD // <-- HERE
        );

        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        if (dwRtnCode != ERROR_SUCCESS) throw new InvalidOperationException("GetSecurityInfo Failed");

        StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder(50);
        uint cchName = (uint)name.Capacity;
        StringBuilder domainName = new StringBuilder(50);
        uint cchDomainName = (uint)domainName.Capacity;
        uint sidUse;

        LookupAccountSid(
            null,
            pSidOwner,
            name,
            ref cchName,
            domainName,
            ref cchDomainName,
            out sidUse);

        Console.WriteLine("Account Owner = {0}", name);
        Console.WriteLine("Account Owner's Domain = {0}", domainName);

        // PLEASE FREE pSD once done 
    }


}
```

### Go

*my second Go program I have ever written so there are probably some blaring mistakes (other than the lack of error checking)*

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
    "os"
)

var (
    advapi32, _ = syscall.LoadLibrary("advapi32.dll")
    kernel32, _ = syscall.LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll")
    createFileW, _ = syscall.GetProcAddress(kernel32, "CreateFileW")
    getSecurityInfo, _ = syscall.GetProcAddress(advapi32, "GetSecurityInfo")
    lookupAccountSidW, _ = syscall.GetProcAddress(advapi32, "LookupAccountSidW")
)

type SE_OBJECT_TYPE uint32
const (SE_FILE_OBJECT = 1)

type SECURITY_INFORMATION uint32
const (OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x00000001)

const (
    GENERIC_READ    = 0x80000000
    FILE_SHARE_READ = 0x00000001
    OPEN_EXISTING   = 0x00000003
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL   = 0x00000080
)

type Handle uintptr

func CreateFile(
    name string,
    access uint32,
    mode uint32,
    sa *uint, // *SecurityAttributes,
    createmode uint32,
    attrs uint32,
    templatefile *uint,
) (handle Handle, err error) {

    utf16name, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(name)

    r0, _, _ := syscall.Syscall9(
        uintptr(createFileW), 7, 
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(utf16name)), 
        uintptr(access), 
        uintptr(mode), 
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(sa)), 
        uintptr(createmode), 
        uintptr(attrs), 
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(templatefile)),
        0, 0)
    handle = Handle(r0)
    return
}

func GetSecurityInfo(
    handle Handle, 
    objectType SE_OBJECT_TYPE, 
    securityInformation SECURITY_INFORMATION, 
    owner **struct{}, 
    group **struct{}, 
    dacl **struct{}, 
    sacl **struct{}, 
    sd **struct{}, //**SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR,
) (ret error) {
    r0, _, _ := syscall.Syscall9(
        uintptr(getSecurityInfo), 8, 
        uintptr(handle), 
        uintptr(objectType), 
        uintptr(securityInformation), 
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(owner)), 
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(group)), 
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(dacl)), 
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(sacl)), 
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(sd)), 
        0)
    if r0 != 0 {
        ret = syscall.Errno(r0)
    }
    return
}

func LookupAccountSid(
    systemName *uint16,
    sid *struct{}, // *SID,
    name *uint16,
    nameLen *uint32, 
    refdDomainName *uint16,
    refdDomainNameLen *uint32,
    use *uint32,
) (err error) {
    r, _, e := syscall.Syscall9(
        uintptr(lookupAccountSidW), 7, 
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(systemName)), 
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(sid)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(name)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(nameLen)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(refdDomainName)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(refdDomainNameLen)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(use)),
        0, 0)
    if r == 0 {
        err = e
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    defer syscall.FreeLibrary(advapi32)
    defer syscall.FreeLibrary(kernel32)

    // get the executing program's file path and handle
    var hFile, _ = CreateFile(os.Args[0], GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, nil);

    // defer LocalFree(Handle(unsafe.Pointer(pSD))) // PLEASE FREE pSD once done 

    // vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

    var pSD *struct{} //*SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR
    var pSidOwner *struct{}
    GetSecurityInfo(hFile, SE_FILE_OBJECT, OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION, &pSidOwner, nil, nil, nil, &pSD)

    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    nameLen := uint32(50)
    name := make([]uint16, nameLen)

    domainLen := uint32(50)
    domainName := make([]uint16, domainLen)

    var sidUse uint32

    LookupAccountSid(nil, pSidOwner, &name[0], &nameLen, &domainName[0], &domainLen, &sidUse)

    var n = syscall.UTF16ToString(name)
    var dn = syscall.UTF16ToString(domainName)

    fmt.Printf("Account Owner = %s\n", n)
    fmt.Printf("Account Owner's Domain = %s\n", dn)
}
```

Comment: This was all extremely informative. Thank you for the write-up. I've tried a few approaches getting what I learned here to work but I can't seem to get it. That being said, you put a lot of effort in this and while it didn't solve my exact problem, it was highly informative. Take the bounty!